# How to save application/octet-stream to Sql Server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to upload files with Ajax (Valums Ajax File Upload) in ASP.NET MVC3, my codes works fine for IE but not for Firefox nor Chrome, I get application/octet-stream for those on server side, how can I read and convert this to byte[] in order to save them in DB? thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question, what browsers have to do with server side storing to DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the Request Stream into a `MemoryStream` and then reading all bytes from the memory stream will give you a `byte[]`

Comment: I did so but it only inserts 0x in DB, I have code like this : MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    stream.CopyTo(ms);
                    byte[] byts = ms.ToArray();